# Some site logos are hardly visible in the app sites list

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, ios-app, logo

The icon of Meta Stack Overflow is hardly visible in the iOS app on the dark background.

> [image: Screenshot]

This transcends the importance of meta, potentially affecting even sites themselves.

It is already happening to [Software Recommendations SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com):

> [image: Software Recommendations SE affected too]

Can there be done anything to fix this?

Comment: Well, same in the android app, both have a dark-ish background. Not sure how it can be solved though

Comment: You *could* reorder your list so MSO is in the dark blue section where it has more contrast. I've been toying with the idea of merging the phone and iPad menus for a while.  Tablet is a shade of gray that [seems to work nicely with metas](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdE9s.png).